# Instantiate MovieClip with its layers?

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe

I have searched a lot lately, I found that I can load an external swf file to my haxe project at compile time, and use the movieClips via their IDs as Classes types ..

That's cool& nice, but how it would work when I instantiate a MovieClip that has layers?
What I have is MovieClips with layers, layer of image, and a layer of text over the image layer.

So, is this achievable? will I be seeing instances of movieClips (images& texts over them) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't spent a lot of time in flash, but the answer to your question comes from having a better understanding of how Flash/AS3 works, and not so much to do with Haxe.

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5486688/180995):

> Layers only exist in the Flash IDE. They are not part of Flash Player's display list system. So you can't specify what layer a child goes into. Use addChild() or addChildAt() to add children to containers.

So that means Haxe will not have any concept which object is in which layer, nor would AS3 for that matter.  The correct approach seems to be to use containers with IDs, which are recognised by AS3 or Haxe, and then add children to the containers.

TLDR: use containers movie clips, not layers.

Comment: But, Flash IDE provided me a great help to organize the final look of what I want, if I want to depend totally on addChild, and place childs at different locations by my self, it will be harder, How would I benefit from already organized/layerd/located childs of a MovieClip within a swf library file?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first dissect the flash terms in terms of code,

**Layers :**

Consider the layers as grouped z indexes. A single layer with multiple objects will also assign sub z indexes to each clip (see the *send to back* option in context menu)

The flash IDE provides you a nice interface to group & lock a few instances of objects, while working on the other. Each such group is a layer.

At runtime, every layer (with it's objects) will be concatenated into one single list (the display list) and the objects placed onto the stage in order of their position in the list.

**Frames :**

Frames are slices of time controlled by the fps property of the flash player. So if you have 12 fps, it means that whatever code you put in that frame of time will receive attention for 1/12th of a second.

Of course there is code being written for anything you do inside a frame or layer. The code, for example that you put in manually in IDE is added in by calling the *addframescript* internally.

**MovieClip**

The MovieClip class itself is actually an IDE related thing. The split being Sprite Class plus a timeline (collection of frames) plus associated properties & methods.

The Movieclip class thus provides you with properties like currentFrame, totalFrames, etc & methods like gotoAndPlay(), stop(), etc to interact with the flash controlled class.

---

Considering all of the above together, you should expect to see different images/text/objects at different intervals of time as defined in the frames when you access the movieclip.